# PhoneGap jquery moble timeout (never hits)

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm making requests from phonegap-build to my webserver, but my time-outs are never hit (as below you can see i've tried to set the timout to 5000ms for testing...when the server doesn't respond, I can't work out why, any ideas?

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://somedomain.com/Register.asmx/Login",
    data: { UserName: user, Password: password },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: onDataReceived,
    error: noDataReceived
});

function onDataReceived(data)
{
    $.mobile.loading( 'hide', { theme: "b", text: "", textonly: false});

    if(data.SessionID.length > 7){
        localStorage.setItem("SessionID",data.SessionID);
        localStorage.setItem("Username", $('#homeUserName').val());
        console.log("Session Login Set");
        reReg();

        $.mobile.changePage("#mainpage");


    } else {
        console.log("Password error, not Set");

        function alertDismissed() {

        }
        navigator.notification.alert('Sorry, incorrect login credentials.', alertDismissed, 'Error', 'Okay' );

    }
}

function noDataReceived(x, t, m)
{
    $.mobile.loading( 'hide', { theme: "b", text: "", textonly: false});
        navigator.notification.alert('Sorry, no data returned. Are you connected to the internet?', alertDismissed, 'Error', 'Okay' );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by time-out never hit? Is the error callback fired immediatly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following methods depending on which JQ version you use. This is untested as i dont have a json url to work with.

**jQuery 1.8+**

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://somedomain.com/Register.asmx/Login",
    data: { UserName: user, Password: password },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    timeout:5000 //5 second timeout
}).done(function(){
    //do something

   onDataReceived(data);


}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    if(textStatus == 'timeout')
    {     
        alert('Failed from timeout'); 
        //do something. Try again perhaps?
    }
});​
```

**jQuery <= 1.7.2**

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://somedomain.com/Register.asmx/Login",
    data: { UserName: user, Password: password },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        if(textStatus == 'timeout')
        {     
             alert('Failed from timeout');         
            //do something. Try again perhaps?
        }
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something

    onDataReceived(data);

    },
    timeout:5000 //5 second timeout
});
```